# Repeat html unit with incremental ids

Tags: jquery, html

I have following html unit.

```
<div id="unit">
  <div id="***-group-x">****</div>
  <div id="***-group-x">****</div>
  <div id="***-group-x">****</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="***-group-x" />
</div>
```

I need to repeat this html unit on a button click with an incremental id as bellow,

when click on first time,
`***-group-x` -> `***-group-1`

when click on second time,
`***-group-x` -> `***-group-2`

I tried like bellow and it doesn't work,

```
var html = $('#unit').html();
newhtml = html .replace('group-x', 'group-3');
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Looks like a template, so use it like a template. Clone the original, and insert it where you want, each time you want a new one. Note: Replace only replaces the first occurrence, unless you use a regex.

Comment: yes, i need this like template, and when repeating I need to change the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice pattern for using templated HTML is to hide it in a script block of unknown type:

```
<script id=unit" type="text/template">
    <div id="***-group-x">****</div>
</script>
```

This make maintenance very easy as *what you see is what you get* :)

Access it with `$('#unit').html()`

Convert any replacement markers (with a regex, if they occur more than once as replace only does the first match) and insert in the new location:

```
   var html = $('#unit').html().replace('group-x', 'group-' + n);

   $('#targetlocationselector').append(html);
```

Mangaging the number depends on your usage.

e.g. you may want to count the number of them already present and add one to that:

```
  var n = $('#targetlocationselector').children().length;
```

To use a regex in the replace, you either pass a RegExp object instead of a string, or use a regex *literal* instead (suitable in this case):

```
  var html = $('#unit').html().replace(/group-x/g, 'group-' + n);
```

Comment: this answered my question so I mark the same, but if you don't mind just put how to do `regx` replacement.

Comment: Updated to show use of regex literal for multiple replacement (not tested as typed from memory, but should be close enough)

Comment: thanks for the help, it still change the first occurrence only. anyway I try to find out.

Comment: Thanks (updated). I knew something was missing. Call it an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Regular expressions with templates like create a template.

```
<div id="element-templates" style="display: none ;">
        <div id="::FIELD1::">****</div>
</div>
```

and use script code like.

```
var jFilesContainer = $("#unit");
var jUploadTemplate = $("#element-templates div:first");
var jUpload = jUploadTemplate.clone();
var strNewHTML = jUpload.html();
var intNewFileCount = (jFilesContainer.find("div").length + 1);
strNewHTML = strNewHTML.replace(new RegExp("::FIELD1::", "i"), intNewFileCount)
jFilesContainer.append(jUpload);
```

Comment: Wow... Upvoted so soon after it was posted I did not have time to read it... That's impressive. Especially as it will not run (`checkHtml` is not defined)

Answer (score 0):

You can do increment by this code and further things you can add up as per your requirements.

```
var i=0;
$('.unit').each(function(){
    i++;
    var newID='menu'+i;
    $(this).attr('id',newID);
    $(this).val(i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 1;
$("#your_button_id").click(function(){
    $("#unit div").eq(x-1).attr("id","***-group-"+x);  
    x++;
});
```